# MS Access Form Development: Hide Objects when an Option Button is Pressed without coding for each Object that needs to be hidden

Tags: forms, object, ms-access, tabcontrol, subforms

MS Access Development Question:

I have 3 options and I need each one associated with a different set of objects. Therefore, if you click option 1, a set of objects will appear in a box I'm referring to as "Report Parameters". If I click option 2, the objects in the "Report Parameters" box will disappear and a new set of objects will appear.

I didn't want to write code to switch each object from visible = true to visible = false. I thought that would take too long, especially if the number of option buttons or the objects related to it grow.

So I'm trying several things...

I tried putting all objects, that relate to a particular option, in a **Subform**. Therefore, I would have three subforms and that would sit in the same position on my main form. When you click on an option, the subform for that option is made visible any anything else is hidden. But I have a background picture that needs to be visible on the main form and you can't make the subform background transparent.

I used **Tab Controls**; however, I didn't want to use the tabs to control the switch between objects. I can hide the tabs but you can still switch between them if you click the space where the tab should be. It can be made transparent though so that helps a lot.

I need something in-between a **Subform** and **Tab Control** but I've hit a dead end. Does anyone have any other suggestions or recommendations? Or am I stuck coding for each object?

I'm an experienced VBA developer. My last option was to run a query against the form and pull all object names and save it to a table. Since the syntax of the name for each object connects it to a button, I can always run a loop that makes all objects visible/invisible if the object's name corresponds with a specific option... but... I guess I'm trying to find a shortcut. Let me know what you think! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue. I just needed to do some thinking... so writing up this question was a bit premature. I'll write down what I did in the event that someone has the same issue I have.

First, I used the **Tab Control** object to resolve my issue. I made the control transparent and named each page to reflect the Option Button I was selecting.

I then mapped each option to a button in the VBA code of the button. Therefore, when the button is selected it does several things.

First, it makes the default value of any of the other options equal to *false*. I also set the visibility of their corresponding pages to *false*.

Second, I select the page I need visible and set the visibility to *true*. I also make it my active page.

Lastly, as a safety measure, if the option button is already selected, and you select it again, by setting the value of that option to *true*. This is to prevent it from changing to *false*. One option should always be selected.

Hope that all made sense!